# События onmouseover и onmouseout отказываются работать в FF

Tags: javascript, firefox

```
<input type="submit" name="form[Submit]" id="Submit"    
       onmouseover="this.style.backgroundPosition='0 -32px !important'" 
       onmouseout="this.style.backgroundPosition='0 0px !important'">
```

Везде работает, а в FF нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

!important нужно убрать

Comment: Здорово... решение оказалось очень простым... осталось понять почему так происходит... ведь параметр строковый, какая ему разница до этого !important

Comment: А зачем здесь вообще используется !important? это же указатель приоритета, который устанавливается для разрешения разногласий между пользовательским стилем и авторским